# Subjects of the Lord (God)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that defines the subjects/things that have a Lord (with respect to the Divine) over them. The closest that I have come across is `exercise lordship over` from [Bible Truth Publisher](http://bibletruthpublishers.com/have-dominion-over-Lord-be-Lord-of-exercise-lordship-over/ljm2961) which would result in the folllowing:

> Those that have lordship exercised over them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in referring to the people, as your example has, I would simply use that which is stated in your title: `Subjects of the LORD [our GOD]`.

`Lordship` has connotations of a medieval lord, whereas `subjects` is still in common usage. People under a monarchical government, for example, are a monarch's subjects, or subjects of a monarch. I have not heard them referred to as those who have lordship exercised over them.

Comment: I would also like it to include inanimate objects as occurs in the title 'Lord of the Heavens and the Earth'. So in this case, what would the Heavens and the Earth be called?

Comment: @KhalidHussain -- In the sense you describe, the "Heavens and Earth" would be the Lord's *domain*.